Capture Composable to bitmap without rendering them
i made a simple app which makes you an id card when you open the id card it shows the details with the card design that you can print. the whole card design looks good in preview but when i use different device the proportions are messed up so i thought of a different idea but i don't know how to implement it as i am new to this.
what i want to do is make the card with fixed dp size so its proportions don't mess up in different screens then capture it into a bitmap somehow and finally show the bitmap scaled according to users screen to fit perfectly and dont show the fixed size card on screen.
i believe this steps only have to happen once because the card dont change in run time so once i capture it into bitmap i dont need it
P.S. the cards aspect ratio is 1f / 1.58f
is this possible? if yes how?
